# is a way to done a call in hasura with blank pass?

Tags: docker-compose, hasura

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres
        volumes:
            - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=''
    graphql-engine:
        image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.0.1
        ports:
        - "8080:8080"
        depends_on:
        - "postgres"
        restart: always
        environment:
            HASURA_GRAPHQL_METADATA_DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://postgres@postgres:5432/postgres'
            ## enable the console served by server
            HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
            ## enable debugging mode. It is recommended to disable this in production
            HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE: "true"
            HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES: startup, http-log, webhook-log, websocket-log, query-log
            ## uncomment next line to set an admin secret
            # HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: myadminsecretkey
```

i have this docker compose who i'm testing hasura and i am tring to connect to a postgres server who i created with a blank pass, is there a way to achieve this or only with a password?

Comment: You need unauthentificated access to hasura? Maybe that is what you want: https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/auth/authentication/unauthenticated-access.html#no-auth-setup ?

Comment: at really i was trying to connect hasura in a existente database with blank pass who i was testing but i understood about hasura need a db to create some schema to connect after in a remote db

Comment: In hasura 2.0 you can create hasura metadata in another database. So you can have local db with `hdb_catalog/hdb_views` and connect to remote db without need to change it. But you need permissions for `hasurauser` set